# Where can I find a repository of all Kodi software versions?

Tags: kodi

I have recently installed the latest Kodi version (i.e. v19.9) on my mobile device. However, this version no longer supports the installation of most add-ons from the Kelebek add-on. Does anybody know if there exists any online repository which stores mirrors of old Kodi software versions? For example, v18.9 was fully compatible with Kelebek.

Many thanks!

Marioanzas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All mirrors can be downloaded here: http://mirrors.kodi.tv/releases/android/arm/